# Data from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

So Google Analytics does not have an API that we can use to get our data, so is there an efficient way to programaticly fetch the data collected by Google, without logging it locally?

Edit:
I would prefer a Python or PHP solution but anything will work.

Comment: They *do* have an API for exporting your data:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html

Comment: Correct they do have an API now, however when the question was written Oct '08 they didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, I forgot about this: I never actually completely implemented this for a client because the deal fell through...

But you can customize the dashboard to include the sections of Google Analytics that your report might need and have a scheduled email.  If the reports do not need to be too detailed and if Google already aggregates the data in the way you need it, then this might work for you.

Comment: just a followup question on privacy, will changing the page tag be sufficient such that users of Google Analytics Account B will not be able to see data and stats from Account A? Both accounts are targeting the same website

Answer (score 9):

Google just announced that they're [making available a data export API for Google Analytics](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2008/10/more-enterprise-class-features-added-to.html). It sounds like that's exactly what you're looking for.

Per their announcement, the feature's currently in private beta, but I figure it'll be rolled out to all accounts in coming weeks/months. Depending on your needs, you may just want to wait, instead of building a short-term hackish solution.

If you're interested, I presume that the functionality's being rolled out first to members of the [Google Analytics Trusted Tester](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/trustedTester.html) program.

Comment: At Google, they use beta and beta. Gmail is in beta too, but also my main e-mailprovider for the last 4 years....

Comment: just a followup question, will changing the page tag be sufficient such that users of Google Analytics Account B will not be able to see data and stats from Account A? Both accounts are targeting the same website

Answer (score 2):

The [Google Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html) is now open to everyone and looks like it contains the full data set

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you want to do with the data. If you only want to process part of it, then I don't think it is difficult.

Here's a basic web search with a hit explanations from Google and someone else:
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55561
http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2008-01-17-n73.html

Comment: First link I have seen, and none of the options given by google are programmatic, unless I'm going to write a reminder program :( The second I have seen but I was hoping for less of a hack.  +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

There is a completely programmatic way to access the data using greqo(PHP), but the analytics class is in beta. Check it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/greqo/).

If beta is not acceptable, you can use a mixture of the XML and Yahoo Pipes to get what you need.

> Basic Method
>
> Obtain the tracking data in a usable
>   format – We can schedule Google
>   Analytics to email this as an XML file
>   on a regular basis.
>
> Make the XML file accessible online –
>   By emailing an attachment to Google
>   Groups, the file is automatically
>   given a public URL.
>
> Work out the URL of the most recent
>   report – Since Google Groups provides
>   RSS/Atom feeds for all messages, we
>   can easily find the URL of the most
>   recent message and therefore work out
>   the URL of the XML report.
>
> Prepare the data for use – We need to
>   manipulate the XML and massage it into
>   a handy JSON format that we can use on
>   our blog, which can all be done using
>   Yahoo Pipes.

Taken from [here](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2008-01-17-n73.html).

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a solution where we scheduled the analytics report to be emailed to a gmail account each day and I pulled the report on demand via POP3.  It's pretty easy and works fast.  I've heard Epic1 will do this for you as well.  I'm researching that now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python, Pandas io is also very helpful.  Pandas has an interface on top of the Google Analytics API. It's pretty simple to get up and running and integrates with Pandas so you get the aggregation, time series features, and other data analysis library features.

instructions on how to authenticate and shows examples: http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/pandas-google-analytics.html

more examples: http://quantabee.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/google-analytics-pandas/

I've also posted a few queries to get started
https://github.com/sk8asd123/ga_pandas

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I had to deal with this, but Google Analytics has an XML output type, so you can parse that to get the data in your own system.  However, I believe that there is no way to get the xml file programatically, so someone still has to go in and generate the file and feed it to your app.

Good question though, I'd love to see if there is a 100% automated solution.

Comment: This is what I'm hoping for, I want to be able to send customized reports to my clients each month so they know whats going on without me having to remember to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We just released a product - [Megalytic](http://megalytic.com) - that makes it very easy to create custom reports using data from the Google Analytics API.  You can email these reports to others without sharing your Google Analytics account.  Also, create links to reports, download as PDF, etc.

Comment: Hi Mark, even with a disclaimber promoting your tool 5 times within an hour could be seen a borderline spam.

Comment: Good point.  I try to contribute useful technical content to stackoverflow, and occasionally drop in a comment about Megalytic when it seems appropriate.  In this case, I would agree with you that I went overboard.